# Create txt file with 3 columns from csv file

Tags: csv, unix

I am trying to create a txt file with 3 columns to use as a timing file for fMRI analysis.
I need to extract the information from one column in a csv file, and add two numbers that are constant for all rows.

The data are organised with titles for each columns representing a variable each, and otherwise numbers.

I'm having some trouble with this:

1. In the csv file, many rows are blank. I'm not a great coder, so everything I have tried in unix does not give me a txt file with 3 columns. I only get 2 columns in the rows that are blank in the csv file. Naively, I've tried stuff like:
   awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $40, "2", "1"}' infile.csv > outfile.txt
2. I would prefer choosing columns to extract based on its title (e.g. "reactiontime") instead of its number ($40). Is it possible to do this somehow?
3. In my attempts, the data is still comma separated in the txt file, and I would prefer to change them to tab separated.

Does anyone have a general tip or piece of code on solving this kind of problem?
I would learn a lot from that and it would also help my immediate issue.

Best,
Andreas

The output I want is something like this:
2   2   1
4   2   1
5.5 2   1
7   2   1
8.8 2   1
9   2   1
11  2   1
12.2    2   1
15.5    2   1
20  2   1
21  2   1
25.5    2   1
27  2   1

The input looks like this:
trials_demo.thisRepN,trials_demo.thisTrialN,trials_demo.thisN,trials_demo.thisIndex,trials.thisRepN,trials.thisTrialN,trials.thisN,trials.thisIndex,img.started,img.stopped,key_resp.keys,key_resp.rt,key_resp.started,key_resp.stopped,startClick.started,startClick.stopped,textGender.started,textGender.stopped,choiceGender.response,choiceGender.rt,choiceGender.started,choiceGender.stopped,click.started,click.stopped,key_resp_3.keys,key_resp_3.rt,key_resp_3.started,key_resp_3.stopped,nextClick.started,nextClick.stopped,key_resp_2.keys,key_resp_2.rt,key_resp_2.started,key_resp_2.stopped,infoText.started,infoText.stopped,demo.response,demo.rt,demo.started,demo.stopped,foler.started,foler.stopped,instruksjoner.started,instruksjoner.stopped,happy.started,happy.stopped,sad.started,sad.stopped,fix_test1.started,fix_test1.stopped,fix_test2.started,fix_test2.stopped,text.started,text.stopped,key_scannerwait.keys,key_scannerwait.rt,key_scannerwait.started,key_scannerwait.stopped,profileImg_4.started,profileImg_4.stopped,you_2.started,you_2.stopped,yblack_2.started,yblack_2.stopped,nblack_2.started,nblack_2.stopped,fix1_2.started,fix1_2.stopped,fix2_2.started,fix2_2.stopped,profileImg_2.started,profileImg_2.stopped,word_2.started,word_2.stopped,tilbakemelding_2.started,tilbakemelding_2.stopped,attraktiv_2.response,attraktiv_2.rt,attraktiv_2.started,attraktiv_2.stopped,attraktivTekst_2.started,attraktivTekst_2.stopped,profileImg_3.started,profileImg_3.stopped,moodRating.response,moodRating.rt,moodRating.history,moodRating.started,moodRating.stopped,foler_2.started,foler_2.stopped,happy_2.started,happy_2.stopped,sad_2.started,sad_2.stopped,instruksjoner_2.started,instruksjoner_2.stopped,fix1r.started,fix1r.stopped,fix2r.started,fix2r.stopped,participant,session,date,expName,psychopyVersion,frameRate,
,,,,,,,,9.808291642460063,None,s,1.6973256938272243,10.258865118647009,None,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,143,1,2020_Feb_07_1705,findr,3.2.4,59.768517041775716,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9.808291642460063,None,12.015022674224383,None,Menn,0.9867124325364784,12.015022674224383,None,12.910541409969483,None,s,0.6776523915204962,12.910541409969483,None,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,143,1,2020_Feb_07_1705,findr,3.2.4,59.768517041775716,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,13.612686069261144,None,r,23.58497321998675,16.580722495828013,None,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,143,1,2020_Feb_07_1705,findr,3.2.4,59.768517041775716,
0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,13.612686069261144,None,None,None,3.002709451733608,None,43.17218368482372,49.17307505178451,43.17218368482372,49.17307505178451,43.17218368482372,49.17307505178451,43.17218368482372,49.17307505178451,40.19522619822328,42.705546306123324,42.67223233843197,43.17218368482372,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,143,1,2020_Feb_07_1705,findr,3.2.4,59.768517041775716,
1,0,1,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,None,None,3.0083721569972113,None,52.18802669584511,58.18914552356,52.18802669584511,58.18914552356,52.18802669584511,58.18914552356,52.18802669584511,58.18914552356,49.20497252200221,51.70471324137725,51.688084382191846,52.18802669584511,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,143,1,2020_Feb_07_1705,findr,3.2.4,59.768517041775716,
2,0,2,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,16,5.703,3.003153287607347,None,61.187218265838055,None,61.187218265838055,None,61.187218265838055,None,61.187218265838055,None,58.204176409363754,60.703914254686424,60.68726815118316,61.187218265838055,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,143,1,2020_Feb_07_1705,findr,3.2.4,59.768517041775716,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,66.92143940778078,None,s,52.06480291182652,66.92143940778078,None,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,143,1,2020_Feb_07_1705,findr,3.2.4,59.768517041775716,

etc.

Comment: please add a sample input and output file

Comment: Has been added :)

Comment: Please paste here (or in another service) you csv andh share the link https://pastebin.com/ . Copying for you example input, it' all in one row